# How to get the labels of a particular thread using Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

As I understand it, user labels can be applied to threads and messages. The thread's labels may different from the labels of the messages in the thread. It's clear where to find the labels of each message, because the Users.messages resource object contains an array called labelIds ─ see here:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource.

However, there's no such array in the Users.threads resource ─ see here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads#resource

Where can I find the labels for a particular thread? Thanks.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, for example, [the method of Users.threads: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get) is used, there is ``labelIds`` in ``messages[]``. You can use this as the fields like ``messages/labelIds``, In this case, the response of each element of ``messages[]`` is the same with [the response retrieved by the method of Users.messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource). If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to retrieve labels which are associated with the thread, not the messages, because I understood that labels can be associated with threads or messages. But now I think I'm wrong ─ labels are only associated with a thread indirectly, ie via the messages in the thread. You can add a label to a thread (which adds the label to all the messages), and you can remove a label from a thread (which removes the label from all the messages). So it would be logical to be able to fetch the labels of a thread (ie fetch all the labels of all the messages). But apparently you can't.

Comment: I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.